# Send some values through url to .svc service

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have a service on my website that works well but now I want to pass some values through url. Is this possible?

Service url: http://example.com/Service.svc

I use it like:

```
ChannelFactory<IService> factory = new ChannelFactory<IService>("myKeyBinding");
IService service = factory.CreateChannel();
service.Method(value);
```

What I want is: Service url: http://example.com/Service.svc?some=value&another=value
And use these values on my website.

Comment: That's not how it works. You have a WCF service there, i.e. SOAP. You don't pass values by query string in SOAP, but you send them in the request body. So basically, you need to add a parameter to the services method in your code. If you don't understand what I am saying, try to find a beginners tutorial on WCF.

Comment: you can add a restfull endpoint to your service to acoomplish this

Comment: Yes you are right, I just thought I can use query string.

Answer (score 1):

WCF do support restful behaviour. It's easy:

First mark your contracts with `WebInvoke`

```
[WebInvoke(UriTemplate = "Method/{some}/{another}", Method = Get, ResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json, BodyStyle = WebMessageBodyStyle.Bare)]
string Method(string some, string another);
```

Create a new ServiceBehavior with following metadata:

```
<serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled=”true”/>
```

Create a new endpoint based on this behavior. It should have binding as `wsHttpBinding`

Now, call your service like:

```
http://example.com/Service.svc/Method?some=value&another=value
```